# Change html select in twig+formbuilder

Tags: symfony, twig, formbuilder

I would like know how can I change this:

```
<select id="mifid-proprio" name="mifid-proprio">
    <option value="{{ personne.id }}">{{ personne.prenom }} {{ personne.nom }}</option>
    {% for key, proprietaire in proprietaires %}
        <option value="{{ proprietaire.destination.id }}">{{ proprietaire.destination.prenom }} {{ proprietaire.destination.nom }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

into Twig + Formbuilder (Symfony 2).

Comment: Your question is unclear, it's in twig already, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to build that widget in the FormBuilder. If I am right you should take a look at the documentation of the [choice Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html). When the data you want to display in that select box comes from a database you should take a look at the [entity Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html). If you have never worked with the FormBuilder before, you should also read how to [create form classes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes).

If you build that widget in the FormBuilder you can output it in Twig with:

```
{{ form_widget(form.field_name) }}
```

When you are not satisfied with the generated HTML code you can overwrite it, either on a per-template or global basis. You can read more about [form theming](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-theming).